# How can I add the style text-decoration: line-through with JavaScript when the checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a To-Do App in HTML, CSS and Vanilla JavaScript, but I get the error checkBox is undefined when I try to toggle the class completed (which has text-decoration: line-through) on my checkBox constant. Does anybody know how to make this work?
Edit: I added HTML and CSS codes.
My code is as following:

```js
function addTask() {
  const checkBox = document.createElement("INPUT");
  checkBox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  let task = document.createElement("li");
  let inputVal = document.getElementById("taskName").value;

  if (inputVal === "") {
    alert ("Luilak!")
    return
  }

  task.innerHTML = inputVal;
  taskItem.appendChild(task);
  taskItem.appendChild(checkBox);
 
  let taskList = [];
  taskList.push(inputVal);
}

if (checkBox.checked === true) {
  taskItem.classList.toggle("completed", true)
} else {
  taskItem.classList.toggle("completed", false)
}
```

```css
html {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: arial;

}

h2 {
    font-family: arial;
    font-style: italic;
}
 #add {
  background-color: hsl(185,100%,50%);
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
 }

.completed {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

li {
    font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="Script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To-Do App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>To-Do App</h1>
    <h2>Today</h2>
    <ul id="taskItem"></ul>
    <input type="text" id="taskName" value=""> <br>
    <button onclick="addTask()" type="button" id="add">Add task</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide HTML and CSS codes

Comment: You have defined `checkBox ` inside function and trying to access outside it.

Comment: Make what work? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Your code errors... Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onchange` event.

You are directly checking `checkBox.checked === true` inside the function, this will check only once. Tis must be done inside the onchange of the checkbox. Inside that check the value of the checkbox and toggle the class of `task`, which is your `li` element.

```js
function addTask() {
  const checkBox = document.createElement("INPUT");
  checkBox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  checkBox.onchange = function(e) {
    if(e.target.checked) {

    }
  }
  let task = document.createElement("li");
  let inputVal = document.getElementById("taskName").value;

  if (inputVal === "") {
    alert("Luilak!")
    return
  }

  task.innerHTML = inputVal;
  taskItem.appendChild(task);
  taskItem.appendChild(checkBox);

  let taskList = [];
  taskList.push(inputVal);
  checkBox.onchange = function(e) {
    if(e.target.checked) {
      task.classList.toggle("completed", true)
    } else {
      task.classList.toggle("completed", false)
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: arial;

}

h2 {
  font-family: arial;
  font-style: italic;
}

#add {
  background-color: hsl(185, 100%, 50%);
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
}

.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

li {
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<h1>To-Do App</h1>
<h2>Today</h2>
<ul id="taskItem"></ul>
<input type="text" id="taskName" value=""> <br>
<button onclick="addTask()" type="button" id="add">Add task</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

this way

```js
const 
  todoList  = document.querySelector('ul#taskItem')
, btAddTask = document.querySelector('button#add')
, task      = document.querySelector('#taskName')
  ;
btAddTask.onclick = e =>
  {
  task.value = task.value.trim()   // remve extra spaces
  if ( task.value === '' )        // control first
    {
    alert ('Luilak!')
    return
    }
  let newLI       = document.createElement('li')
  newLI.innerHTML = `<input type="checkbox"> ${task.value}` // use back quotes system
  task.value      = ''                                     // clear input 4 next usage
  todoList.appendChild(newLI);
  }
todoList.onclick = e => // use event delegation
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('input[type="checkbox"]')) return   // verify clicked element

  e.target.closest('li').classList.toggle('completed', e.target.checked) // 1 line 4 both cases
  }
```

```css
html {
  text-align  : center;
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;    /* same font 4 both elements */
}
h2 {
  font-style : italic;
}
#add {
  background    : hsl(185,100%,50%);
  font-size     : 1.8em;          /* use em unit */
  border-radius : .7em;
  margin        : 1em;
  padding       : .2em .7em;
  }
.completed {
  text-decoration : line-through;
}
#taskItem {
  margin     : .1em auto;
  width      : 12em;
  padding    : 0;
  list-style : none;
  text-align : left;
}
#taskItem li {
  display       : inline-block;
  width         : 100%;
  margin-bottom : .3em;
  padding       : .4em;
  background    : whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<h1>To-Do App</h1>
<h2>Today</h2>

<input  type="text"   id="taskName" value=""> <br>
<button type="button" id="add">Add task</button>

<ul id="taskItem"></ul>
```